# java.sql.SQLException: MONTH

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

please help for my assignment so im building a java program/ folder that has the auto compute of age feature and using JCalendar(JDatechooser)So far i set my dateformatstring of my jdatechooser as "yyyy-MM-dd" so my problem is inserting the chosen date in my sql i set the column of Birthdate as data type date using of course JButton sample code:

```
String query = "insert into walkin (FirstName, MiddleName, Surname, Birthdate, age, gender, address, contact) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";   
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);      
    ps.setString(1, tfname.getText());   
    ps.setString(2, tmname.getText());   
    ps.setString(3, tsname.getText());    
    ps.setString(4, ((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());   
    ps.setString(5, tage.getText());
    ps.setString(6, genderr);   
    ps.setString(7, tadd.getText());  
    ps.setString(8, tcont.getText());
    ps.execute();        
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");         
    ps.close();        
    }
```

Comment: you should be passing an instance of `LocalDate` rater than a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is able to convert a string in format 'yyyy-mm-dd' to DATE and insert in tables. Hence your expectation seems to be correct.

Firstly hard code a date (like following) and run your code to see if mysql is processing the insert successfully and that rest of the values are correctly recorded.

```
ps.setString(4, '2020-01-31');
```

If it works well then clearly the returned information from your widget is not in correct format, try to figure out what it returns by printing it like following an go from there.

```
System.out.println((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Pass objects of an appropriate type to your database. In the case of a date string, parse as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object. Then pass that `LocalDate` object to the prepared statement using [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)) using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supporting [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or later.

So, your line:

```
ps.setString(4, ((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

…should be:

```
String dateInput = (JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText() ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( dateInput ) ;
ps.setString( 4 , ld ) ;
```

If an improper input string were received, the [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) command throws a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).